# Prove: If $n$ is odd, then $ϕ(2n) = ϕ(n)$, and if $n$ is even, then $ϕ(2n) = 2ϕ(n)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove: If $n$ is odd, then $ϕ(2n) = ϕ(n)$, and if $n$ is even, then $ϕ(2n) = 2ϕ(n)$.

As it is the summer, I have been exploring different math topics. I came across this question, and would like to know an answer to this and how to get there as a learning experience. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $ n$ be odd, then $ gcd(n,2) = 1 $. Using that $ \phi $ is multiplicative,

it follows that $ \phi (2n) = \phi (2) \phi (n) = \phi (n) $.

Let $ n$ be even, then $n=2^km, ~k \in \mathbb{Z^{+}},~ m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $gcd(m,2)=1$. Then

$\phi (2n)= \phi (2^{k+1}m)= \phi(2^{k+1})\phi(m)=2^k\phi (m) = 2\cdot2^{k-1}\phi (m) = 2\phi (2^k)\phi(m)=2\phi (2^km)=2\phi(n)$.

Comment: Ahhh! That makes a lot of sense, and cleared up many questions I had. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, the totient is not multiplicative. For example $2=\varphi(4)\neq\varphi(2)\cdot\varphi(2)=1$. But it is arithmetic.

Comment: Yes it is. Your example shows that it is not completely multiplicative.

Answer (score 3):

$\varphi$ is an arithmetic function, for any $m,n$ satisfying gcd($m,n1)=1$ we have $\varphi(m\cdot n)=\varphi(m)\cdot \varphi(n)$.

Now let $n=2^k\cdot m$ where $m$ is an odd natural number. Then $$\varphi(2\cdot n)=\varphi(2^{k+1}\cdot m)=\varphi(2^{k+1})\cdot \varphi(m)$$
If $n$ is even then $k\geq 1$ thus $\varphi(2^{k+1})=2^{k+1}-2^k=2\cdot(2^k-2^{k-1})=2\cdot \varphi(2^k)$ and if $n$ is odd then $k=0$ so $\varphi(2^{k+1})=1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

If $n$ is odd and $\gcd(n,k)=1$ then exactly one of $k$ and $n+k$ is relatively prime to $2n$.

If $n$ is even, and $\gcd(n,k)=1$ then both $k$ and $n+k$ are relatively prime to $2n$.

Comment: I am not too familiar with this topic, which is why I have asked this question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Mathzer Are you familiar with the meaning of $\phi(n)$?  It is, after all, exactly the function you're asking about.

Comment: I have a basic understanding of Euler's totient function. However, I believe this problem would help me understand it and applications of it better, which is why I would like to see a solution of it.

Comment: This is not really a tutoring site, this is a question and answer site. If you have questions, be specific. At list point, I have no idea what would be a satisfactory answer to you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, statements in the hint are very nice. However, they do not seem obvious to me. Can you explain how did you come up with these, please?